# Is there a Scala collection that maintains the order of insert?

Tags: scala

I have a `List:hdtList` which contain columns that represent the columns of a Hive table:

```
forecast_id bigint,period_year bigint,period_num bigint,period_name string,drm_org string,ledger_id bigint,currency_code string,source_system_name string,source_record_type string,gl_source_name string,gl_source_system_name string,year string
```

I have a `List: partition_columns` which contains two elements: `source_system_name, period_year`

Using the `List: partition_columns`, I am trying to match them and move the corresponding columns in `List: hdtList` to the end of it as below:

```
  val (pc, notPc) = hdtList.partition(c => partition_columns.contains(c.takeWhile(x => x != ' ')))
```

But when I print them as: `println(notPc.mkString(",") + "," + pc.mkString(","))`

I see the output unordered as below:

```
 forecast_id bigint,period_num bigint,period_name string,drm_org string,ledger_id bigint,currency_code string,source_record_type string,gl_source_name string,gl_source_system_name string,year string,period string,period_year bigint,source_system_name string
```

The columns `period_year` comes first and the `source_system_name` last. Is there anyway I can make data as below so that the order of columns in the `List: partition_columns` is maintained.

```
 forecast_id bigint,period_num bigint,period_name string,drm_org string,ledger_id bigint,currency_code string,source_record_type string,gl_source_name string,gl_source_system_name string,year string,period string,source_system_name string,period_year bigint
```

I know there is an option to reverse a List but I'd like to learn if I can implement a collection that maintains that order of insert.

Comment: You can use java collections for maintaining the order, like an ArrayList

Comment: Most Scala collections maintain order of insert/append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter which collections you use; you only use `partition_columns` to call `contains` which doesn't depend on its order, so how could it be maintained?

But your code does maintain order: it's just `hdtList`'s.

Something like

```
// get is ugly, but safe here
val pc1 = partition_columns.map(x => pc.find(y => y.startsWith(x)).get)
```

after your code will give you desired order, though there's probably more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Okay. I will try your suggestion. But could you let me know what is the efficient way to implement your are saying here ?

Comment: Given how small your lists are, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Well, okay. This is just a small table I am working on. In production, I have tables with 100odd columns. Should I be worried about it on production for ~100 columns ?

Comment: It's `partition_columns`' size that matters. But 100 is still nothing. I am also assuming this isn't something you are doing constantly.

Comment: You are right. This is the only code I implement this logic.